# Django matching a CharField

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a table in Django using a subset of data from my Model but when I try to filter it I get the following error.

> Unsupported lookup 'like' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.

models.py

```
class Opps(models.Model):
    Rec_ID = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    revenue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    profit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

tables.py part of django_tables2

```
class Opps_Table(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Opps
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
```

views.py

```
def sales(request):
    Data_User = Opps.objects.filter(owner__contains='name')
    table = Opps_Table(Data_User)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'graphs/sales.html', {'table': table} )
```

Should I be using a different type of data in my Model or trying to filter it a different way?

Comment: What is `Opps_Table`? you should show the full traceback and try to make a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry I left that out as it didn't appear to be relevant to the error, it's a part of Django tables2 configuration.  I have added the appropriate .py  I will have a look at creating an example later as it's the end of the day here in Aus.

Comment: can you show the whole traceback pls?